# oracle.xdb.XMLType cannot be cast to java.lang.String error

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jpa, eclipselink

I am using JPA to retrieve data from an Oracle XMLType column. I created a customizer:

```
@Override
public void customize(final ClassDescriptor descriptor) throws Exception {
    descriptor.removeMappingForAttributeName("content");
    DirectToXMLTypeMapping mapping = new DirectToXMLTypeMapping();
    mapping.setAttributeName("content"); //name of the atribute on the Entity Bean
    mapping.setFieldName("CONTENT"); //name of the data base column
    mapping.getField().setColumnDefinition("XMLTYPE");
    descriptor.addMapping(mapping);
}
```

and the column in my entity class is:

```
@Basic(optional = false)
@NotNull
@Lob
//@Column(name = "CONTENT", columnDefinition="XMLTYPE")    
private String content;
```

However, when I run my program I get the error "`java.lang.ClassCastException: oracle.xdb.XMLType cannot be cast to java.lang.String
    at entities.Sqdocument._persistence_set(Sqdocument.java)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.descriptors.PersistenceObjectAttributeAccessor.setAttributeValueInObject(PersistenceObjectAttributeAccessor.java:46)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.mappings.DatabaseMapping.setAttributeValueInObject(DatabaseMapping.java:1532)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.mappings.DatabaseMapping.readFromRowIntoObject(DatabaseMapping.java:1423)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.descriptors.ObjectBuilder.buildAttributesIntoObject(ObjectBuilder.java:448)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.descriptors.ObjectBuilder.buildObject(ObjectBuilder.java:803)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.descriptors.ObjectBuilder.buildObject(ObjectBuilder.java:607)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.descriptors.ObjectBuilder.buildObject(ObjectBuilder.java:564)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ObjectLevelReadQuery.buildObject(ObjectLevelReadQuery.java:777)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ReadObjectQuery.executeObjectLevelReadQuery(ReadObjectQuery.java:462)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ObjectLevelReadQuery.executeDatabaseQuery(ObjectLevelReadQuery.java:1150)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.DatabaseQuery.execute(DatabaseQuery.java:852)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ObjectLevelReadQuery.execute(ObjectLevelReadQuery.java:1109)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ReadObjectQuery.execute(ReadObjectQuery.java:421)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.internalExecuteQuery(AbstractSession.java:2946)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.executeQuery(AbstractSession.java:1602)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.executeQuery(AbstractSession.java:1584)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.indirection.NoIndirectionPolicy.valueFromQuery(NoIndirectionPolicy.java:323)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.mappings.ForeignReferenceMapping.valueFromRowInternal(ForeignReferenceMapping.java:2135)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.mappings.OneToOneMapping.valueFromRowInternal(OneToOneMapping.java:1716)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.mappings.ForeignReferenceMapping.valueFromRow(ForeignReferenceMapping.java:2024)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.mappings.ForeignReferenceMapping.readFromRowIntoObject(ForeignReferenceMapping.java:1369)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.descriptors.ObjectBuilder.buildAttributesIntoObject(ObjectBuilder.java:448)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.descriptors.ObjectBuilder.buildObject(ObjectBuilder.java:803)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.descriptors.ObjectBuilder.buildWorkingCopyCloneNormally(ObjectBuilder.java:719)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.descriptors.ObjectBuilder.buildObjectInUnitOfWork(ObjectBuilder.java:672)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.descriptors.ObjectBuilder.buildObject(ObjectBuilder.java:605)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.descriptors.ObjectBuilder.buildObject(ObjectBuilder.java:564)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ObjectLevelReadQuery.buildObject(ObjectLevelReadQuery.java:777)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ReadAllQuery.registerResultInUnitOfWork(ReadAllQuery.java:783)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ReadAllQuery.executeObjectLevelReadQuery(ReadAllQuery.java:434)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ObjectLevelReadQuery.executeDatabaseQuery(ObjectLevelReadQuery.java:1150)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.DatabaseQuery.execute(DatabaseQuery.java:852)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ObjectLevelReadQuery.execute(ObjectLevelReadQuery.java:1109)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ReadAllQuery.execute(ReadAllQuery.java:393)`
"
What could be the problem? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eclipselink is successfully retrieving the XML type.  The problem is that XMLType is not an instance of String so it can't be automatically converted.

You need to write a Converter to convert between XMLType and String.  You'll also need to write the other side of the converter which goes from String to XMLType, if you want to alter the data in any way.

Take a look at [Conversions and Converters](http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/UserGuide/JPA/Basic_JPA_Development/Mapping/Basic_Mappings/Default_Conversions_and_Converters) for help writing a converter.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I've seen these converters but not sure which one should I use?

Comment: I would recommend using an @Converter element.  Check out http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/api/2.0/org/eclipse/persistence/mappings/converters/Converter.html for the API.